# How do you do 3D rendering in Gtk+ using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk3

I've been searching around the internet a lot for a way to use 3D graphics inside my Gtk application and I have found Gtk Glarea, but I can't find any tutorials. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For posterity, I found https://github.com/ebassi/glarea-example (example app by one of the Gtk developers) useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a demonstration of how to draw a spinning cube in Gtk 3 with OpenGL3.3 in C++:

```
/* OpenGL Area
 *
 * GtkGLArea is a widget that allows custom drawing using OpenGL calls.
 */

// compiling with: g++ gl_draw_area.cpp `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` 
// \ `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lepoxy

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <iostream>

unsigned int WIDTH = 800;
unsigned int HEIGHT = 600;

using glm::mat4;
using glm::vec3;
using glm::lookAt;
using glm::perspective;
using glm::rotate;

const GLchar  *VERTEX_SOURCE =
"#version 330\n"
"in vec3 position;\n"
"in vec3 normal;\n"
"out vec3 transformedNormal;\n"
"out vec3 originalNormal;\n"
"uniform mat4 projection;\n"
"uniform mat4 view;\n"
"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"void main(){\n"
"    gl_Position =  projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);\n"
"    mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(view * model)));\n"
"    transformedNormal = normalMatrix * normal;\n"
"    originalNormal = abs(normal);\n"
"}\n";

const GLchar *FRAGMENT_SOURCE =
"#version 330\n"
"in vec3 transformedNormal;\n"
"in vec3 originalNormal;\n"
"out vec4 outputColor;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"vec3 color = originalNormal;\n"
"float lighting = abs(dot(transformedNormal, vec3(0,0,-1)));\n"
"outputColor = vec4(color * lighting, 1.0f);\n" //constant white
"}";

/* the GtkGLArea widget */
static GtkWidget *gl_area = NULL;

/* The object we are drawing */
static const GLfloat vertex_data[] = {
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0,-1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 

  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 

  -1.0, -1.0,-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 

  -1.0, -1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 

  1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 
  1.0,-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 
  -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 
  -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,

  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, -1.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, -1.0,-1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, -1.0, -1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
  1.0, 1.0, -1.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0

};

long current_frame = 0.0;
long delta_time = 0.0;
GDateTime *last_frame;
int dt = 0;

static GLuint position_buffer;
static GLuint program;
static GLuint vao;

mat4 model = mat4(1.0);


/* Create and compile a shader */
static GLuint
create_shader (int  type)
{
  GLuint shader;
  int status;
  shader = glCreateShader (type);
  if (type== GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER){
    glShaderSource (shader, 1, &FRAGMENT_SOURCE, NULL);
  }
  if (type== GL_VERTEX_SHADER){
    glShaderSource (shader, 1, &VERTEX_SOURCE, NULL);
  }
  glCompileShader (shader);

  glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
  if (status == GL_FALSE)
  {
    int log_len;
    char *buffer;
    glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_len);
    buffer = (char*)g_malloc (log_len + 1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog (shader, log_len, NULL, buffer);
    g_warning ("Compile failure in %s shader:\n%s",
               type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment",
               buffer);
    g_free (buffer);
    glDeleteShader (shader);
    return 0;
  }

  return shader;
}


/* We need to set up our state when we realize the GtkGLArea widget */
static void
realize (GtkWidget *widget)
{
  GdkGLContext *context;
  gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA (widget));
  if (gtk_gl_area_get_error (GTK_GL_AREA (widget)) != NULL)
    return;
  context = gtk_gl_area_get_context (GTK_GL_AREA (widget));

  /* We only use one VAO, so we always keep it bound */
  glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray (vao);

  /* This is the buffer that holds the vertices */
  glGenBuffers (1, &position_buffer);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position_buffer);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertex_data),vertex_data,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
  glVertexAttribPointer (1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray (1);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

  GLuint vertex, fragment;
  int status;
  vertex = create_shader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

  if (vertex == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

  fragment = create_shader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  if (fragment == 0)
    {
      glDeleteShader (vertex);
      return;
    }

  program = glCreateProgram ();
  glAttachShader (program, vertex);
  glAttachShader (program, fragment);

  glLinkProgram (program);

  glGetProgramiv (program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
  if (status == GL_FALSE)
  {
    int log_len;
    char *buffer;

    glGetProgramiv (program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_len);

    buffer = (char*)g_malloc (log_len + 1);
    glGetProgramInfoLog (program, log_len, NULL, buffer);

    g_warning ("Linking failure:\n%s", buffer);

    g_free (buffer);

    glDeleteProgram (program);
    program = 0;

    glDeleteShader (vertex);
    glDeleteShader (fragment);

    return;
  }

  glDetachShader (program, vertex);
  glDetachShader (program, fragment);

  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glFrontFace(GL_CCW);  
  glCullFace(GL_BACK);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

/* We should tear down the state when unrealizing */
static void
unrealize (GtkWidget *widget)
{
  gtk_gl_area_make_current (GTK_GL_AREA (widget));

  if (gtk_gl_area_get_error (GTK_GL_AREA (widget)) != NULL)
    return;

  glDeleteBuffers (1, &position_buffer);
  glDeleteProgram (program);
}

static void
draw_box (long delta_time)
{
  /* Use our shaders */
  glUseProgram (program);

  model = rotate(model, (float)delta_time/1000, vec3(1,1,0));
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
  vec3 position = vec3(0,0,5);
  vec3 front = vec3(0,0,-1);
  vec3 up = vec3(0,1,0);
  mat4 view = lookAt(position, position + front, up);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
  mat4 projection = perspective(45.0, double(WIDTH)/double(HEIGHT), 0.1, 100.0);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]);

  glBindVertexArray(vao);
  /* Use the vertices in our buffer */

  /* Draw the three vertices as a triangle */
  glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

  /* We finished using the buffers and program */
  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray (0);
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glUseProgram (0);
}

static gboolean
render (GtkGLArea    *area,
        GdkGLContext *context)
{
  GDateTime *date_time;

  date_time = g_date_time_new_now_local();  
  current_frame = g_date_time_get_microsecond(date_time);
  delta_time = g_date_time_difference(date_time, last_frame) / 1000;
  last_frame = date_time;

  if (gtk_gl_area_get_error (area) != NULL)
    return FALSE;

  /* Clear the viewport */
  glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  /* Draw our object */
  draw_box (delta_time);
  /* Flush the contents of the pipeline */
  glFlush ();
  gtk_gl_area_queue_render (area);
  return TRUE;
}

static void
on_axis_value_change (void)
{
  gtk_widget_queue_draw (gl_area);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkWidget *window, *box;
  /* initialize gtk */
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  /* Create new top level window. */
  window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window),WIDTH,HEIGHT);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GL Area");
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
  box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, FALSE);
  g_object_set (box, "margin", 12, NULL);
  gtk_box_set_spacing (GTK_BOX (box), 6);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);
  gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new ();
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box), gl_area,1,1, 0);
  /* We need to initialize and free GL resources, so we use
  * the realize and unrealize signals on the widget
  */
  g_signal_connect (gl_area, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (gl_area, "unrealize", G_CALLBACK (unrealize), NULL);

  /* The main "draw" call for GtkGLArea */
  g_signal_connect (gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK (render), NULL);
  /* Quit form main if got delete event */
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "delete-event",
                 G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));
  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image: spinning cube1]

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42205762/9238288) is a "hello triangle" example in `pygtk` if you want a minimal python example.

Comment: Do you know where i can find an example like this with gtk4 ?
I tried to use gtk4 but i draw only the first frame.

Comment: Does `gtk_gl_area_set_auto_render(gl_area, TRUE)` fix it?